# Increase visibility of large scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bioinformatics

I am plotting a dotplot( here is a brief explanation of what it is)https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_plot_(bioinformatics) of a large amount of data( the largest one being 66x80,000x80,000!!).

The current method I'm using is to plot a matplotlib scatter plot with the x,y coordinates of the dots.

the problem is I can not set the interpolation value of the plot, and the output is not a vector graph. This makes the graph very hard to see when zoomed out.

here is the code:

```
v_x = np.random.randint(0, 80000, 300000)
v_y = v_x # the x, y cordinate of the dots.

f,axes = plt.subplots(11,11,figsize = (20,20))
for row in range(11):
    for col in range(11):

        axes[row,col].set_yticklabels([])
        axes[row,col].set_xticklabels([])

        if row > col:
            axes[row,col].axis('off')
        else:
            axes[row,col].set_xlim(0,len(v_x))
            axes[row,col].set_ylim(0,len(v_y))


            axes[row,col].scatter(v_x,v_y, c = '#000000', s=(72./300)**2*20, marker = 's', edgecolor= '', rasterized = True)
f.savefig('{}'.format('test.pdf'), facecolor='w', bbox_inches='tight', dpi = 300)
```

If I don't do the rasteration, the pdf file contains too many dots and cannot be opened, if I do rasteration, the plot is hard to see when zoomed out.

I wonder if there is any way that I can solve this problem.

Comment: Its not really clear from the above what you are trying to plot.  Its not obvious that its a similarity matrix...

Comment: Did you try saving the figure as .eps extension?

Comment: .eps output would work but result in a huge file(more than 50mb) and the quality is low.